# How can I verify the strongAuthenticationEmailAddress in a custom policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

My users connect with a username and provide an email for password recovery, using the default combined signup/signin user flow configured for userId. To be clear, this is the email in the "Authentication contact info" section in B2C.

I want my users to be able to change this email. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/63807/how-to-change-sspr-email-id-when-using-usernamenot.html) got me started on a custom policy and it works but I want the `strongAuthenticationEmailAddress` claim to be verified using standard B2C email verification. I can get the regular email claim to be verified but trying to apply the same logic to strongAuthenticationEmailAddress either does nothing, or entirely skip the step depending on what I try.

So basically I'd want this (or whatever would be the correct way).

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" PartnerClaimType="Verified.strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" Required="true"/>
```

To cause an email verification like this does

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.email" Required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" PartnerClaimType="Verified.email" Required="true"/>
```